# Generating a test file from The Ruby on Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd

Chapter 5 exercise "full_title" test. I tried the pattern from the previous file generation example...

```
$ rails generate integration_test site_layout
```

and when I try

```
$ rails generate helpers_test application_helper,
```

The path I'm supposed to get is `test/helpers/application_helper_test.rb`,  but the error I get is `"Could not find generator 'helpers' "`

Below is the class that is supposed to be generated

```
require 'test_helper
class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  test 'full title helper' do
  ....
  ....
end
end
```

The question is what must I do to generate the correct file in the right location and to get the correct class .

I went to the rails docs, and I reviewed this other question [Hartl Rail Tutorial: Chapter 5, exercise 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127142/hartl-rail-tutorial-chapter-5-exercise-3)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you found reference to a helpers_test generator but it isn't core Rails.

It may depend on what version of Rails you have but you should be able to do:

```
rails g helper application
```

This will generate the following 2 files (assuming you are using Test::Unit)

```
app/helpers/application_helper.rb
test/helpers/application_helper_test.rb
```

This certainly works for Rails 4.x, but for my Rails 5.x setup this generator only created `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` leading me to suspect the tutorial was originally created for Rails 4 and has not been updated correctly for Rails 5.

You can find out what generators you have by simply invoking:

```
rails g --help
```

For further information on a particular generator simply expand upon that by:

```
rails g helper --help
```

Incidentally, there is nothing to stop you simply creating the file yourself in the correct location.

Comment: I got the "helpers_test" by thinking the was the correct command. The version of rails I'm using is 5.0.0.1. If you look at listing 5.37 on the tutorial link.. https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout . That is the file I'm trying to generate.

Comment: Subsequently, I just tried $ rails g helper application and the only file created was the first one, app/helpers/application_helper.rb. The second one was not created

Comment: well the tutorial is incomplete as far as explaining where that particular file came from - generators are useful but as I explained in the solution you can just manually create the file you need if necessary. And yes for Rails 5 i get the same behaviour - I suspect this tutorial was originally for Rails 4 and hasn't been updated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> **Exercise snippet:**
>
> ...by writing a direct test of the full_title helper, which involves
> **creating a file** to test the application helper and then filling in the
> code indicated with FILL_IN in...

Create the file using by the command `touch` followed by the directory and filename into the bash/command line (remember to cd into your rails app):

```
$ touch test/helpers/application_helper_test.rb
```

Then open it up manually and add the following:

```
class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  test "full title helper" do
    assert_equal full_title,         FILL_IN
    assert_equal full_title("Help"), FILL_IN
  end
end
```

Obviously where it says `FILL_IN` you have to write some code:)